# linux bash command separate by space

Tags: linux, bash

so I'm trying to display only columns at a time

first ls -l gives me this

```
drwxr-xr-x 11 stuff stuff      4096 2009-08-22 06:45 lyx-1.6.4
-rw-r--r--  1 stuff stuff  14403778 2009-10-26 02:37 lyx.tar.gz
```

I'm using this:

```
ls -l |cut -d " " -f 1
```

to get this

```
drwxr-xr-x 
-rw-r--r--
```

and it displays my first column just fine. Then I want to see on the second column

```
ls -l |cut -d " " -f 2
```

I only get this

```
11
```

Shouldn't I get

```
11
1
```

?
Why is it doing this?

if I try

```
   ls -l |cut -d " " -f 2-3
```

I get

```
11 stuff
```

There's gotta be an easier way to display columns right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should show the second column:

`ls -l | awk '{print $2}'`

Comment: This will work for all cases except the filename itself when the filename has embedded whitespace.  For that, you may want to use either "awk '{print substr($0, 45)}'" or "ls -l | cut -c45-".

Answer (score 1):

cut considers two sequential delimiters to have an empty field in between.  So the second line:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 stuff stuff
```

has fields:

```
1: -rw-r--r--
2: --empty field--
3: 1
etc.
```

You can use use column fields in cut:

```
ls -l | cut -c13-14
```

Or you can use awk to separate fields (unlink, cut awk will treat sequential delimiters as a single delimiter).